# asp.net web api wrong serialization output

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I inherited a model written in VB.NET that I'm trying to expose as a REST service. I have a class that inherits from a base abstract class. When I try to return a collection of the concrete class, what I get is an empty json representation like this:

[{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Why is this? Is it because of abstract class? I'm using MVC 4 RC. My code:

Abstract class:

```
<Serializable()> _
Partial Public MustInherit Class Topic
   Public Property Topic_Key() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_Topic_Key
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_Topic_Key = value
    End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

Concrete class:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class ProductPortfolio
    Inherits Topic
End Class
```

Api Controller:

```
public class PortfoliosController : ApiController
{
    public List<ProductPortfolio> Get()
    {
        return ProductPortfolio.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your abstract class

```
<System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownType(GetType(ProductPortfolio))>
```